# Provider dependency injection & uglify special case

Tags: angularjs, uglifyjs

I use the security functionality from [angular-app](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app), and there is some funky stuff going on in the authorizationProvider

```
angular.module('security.authorization', ['security.service'])

// You can add them as resolves to routes to require authorization levels
// before allowing a route change to complete
.provider('securityAuthorization', {

  requireUser: ['securityAuthorization', function(securityAuthorization) {
    return securityAuthorization.requireUser();
  }],

  $get: ['security', 'securityRetryQueue', function(security, queue) {
    var service = {

      requireUser: function() {
        //Stuff ...
        return true;
    };

    return service;
  }]
});
```

The provider injects itself into the property 'requireUser', which calls a function returned by the $get factory method. Now, when I try to uglify this (grunt-contrib-uglify), it fails at

```
  requireUser: ['securityAuthorization', function(securityAuthorization) {
    return securityAuthorization.requireUser();
  }]
```

with `Unknown provider: eProvider <- e`. How can I minify this? I have tried the alternative provider declaration (since 1.1.x, it's possible to declare providers like normal factories, i.e. inject the dependencies and let the provider be a function), but that doesn't work either, because it looks for the dependencies in the security.authorization module.

Comment: So, in your `securityAuthorization` provider you are defining a `requireUser`function which is injected with the parent `securityAuthorization` itself, and than, inside the very same `requireUser` function you are calling `requireUser()`? Do you see the problem here.

Answer (score 4):

One of the options for grunt-contrib-uglify is [mangle](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#mangle)

Try adding this into your Uglify config:

```
uglify: {
  options: {
    mangle: false
  }
}
```